# Help with solving a first order inexact initial value problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Been stuck on this for quite a bit. The goal is to find the solution to the initial value problem:

$$(e^{x+y}+e^y)dx + (e^{x+y}+e^x)dy = 0, where...$$
$$y(0)=0$$

So the first thing I did was check for exactness - the equation is in the form $M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy =0$, so taking the partial derivative with respect to y of #M(x,y)# and the same with respect to x of $N(x,y)$ doesn't change either expression. They're not equal, so the equation is inexact. Okay, cool.

Next thing I did was look for an integrating factor - we were taught to check two expressions, $(Nx-My)/N$, and $(My-Nx)/M$. I did that, and both of the resulting expressions were a function of both x and y. In this case, I'm not sure what to do - our textbook only covers the case where one or the other is either a function of x or y only.

Have I made a mistake somewhere? How can I move forwards here? I feel like I need to utilize the initial condition somehow but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Thanks for any advice you can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is separable.

$(e^{x+y}+e^y)dx + (e^{x+y}+e^x)dy = 0$

Dividing by $e^{x+y}$,

$(1 + e^{-x})dx + (1 + e^{-y})dy = 0$

$(1 + e^{-x})dx = -(1 + e^{-y})dy$

Comment: Ah, that's embarrassing. Thank you, I think I just got stuck in thinking it was in the form of an exact equation and forgot that it could be simplified further. After your suggestion it's exact and easy to solve. Thanks again :)

Comment: have gone through it :)